# Use custom mod_wsgi and python with limited access to a shared server

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I've been given access to an Ubuntu machine running Apache 2.4.18 for the purpose of hosting a small web application I've developed in Flask.  I'm a user without root privileges.  The system administrator has kindly installed `mod_wsgi` for me, but this module is linked against the system python, which is version 2.7, and I'd like to use python >= 3.6.  I've therefore compiled my own python 3.7 and my own `mod_wsgi` on this machine, and am having trouble getting Apache to use it.  Is this possible?

I've tried adding a `LoadModule wsgi_module .../mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86-64-linux-gnu.so` line to `var/www/html/whatever/.htaccess`, but have learned that this is not allowed at the `Directory` level of the configuration.  I've also tried using `WSGIDaemonProcess user python-home=...`, but this also causes Apache to return an Internal Server Error.

To make matters worse, I do not have permissions on `var/log/apache2`, so I can't see any Apache output except what it's serving.

Is it possible to point Apache to my own `mod_wsgi` and `python` binaries without having access to the root configuration of Apache or the system?  If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to override mod_wsgi in a virtualhost. I would suggest trying this out on e.g. a Linode server first so you have full access to the system, then you can go to your kind sysadmin with a setup you know is working.

Comment: @thebjorn, good idea!  Maybe I'll get a little Ubuntu VM somewhere and try to mimic the configuration there, so that I don't have to iterate with the machine owner too much.

Comment: It's always good to keep your sysadmin happy ;-)  A reverse proxy solution like Marks suggests (e.g. gunicorn) is also a good idea since it isolates your app from Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can only run Apache with a single version of mod_wsgi at any one time.  This means that all apps must use the same version of Python, which is a problem I have run into before.  I think your options are:

a) Persuade the sysadmin to switch to your version.  It is fine to use a version of Python that is different to system Python.

b) Have a look at something like Gunicorn.  That is more separated from Apache, so will allow apps to use different versions of Python on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I like the idea of using Gunicorn, but it seems either way I'll need help from the admin, since `ProxyPass`  can't be used in `Directory` context either.